# Python flask checkbox does not change value back to false onclick in HTML view

Tags: jquery, python, html, checkbox

I noticed that 4 of my checkboxes do not change the value back to false if clicked on them. I am unsure wether it always have been like that. Actually I remember it had worked fine.

I searched now for 2 hours everywhere and still cant find a reason why this happens, I mean all the other checkboxes do work fine.

I am even trying to restore this default behaviour with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".zimmer-gefunden")[0]) {
    $("#einzelzimmer_first").change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("#einzelzimmer_first").prop('checked', false);
      } else {
        $("#einzelzimmer_first").prop('checked', true);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[That](http://www.monteurzimmer-1a.de/suche/Dortmund/1) is the website where the problem occures, the checkboxes are `EINZELZIMMER`, `DOPPELZIMMER`, `MEHRBETTZIMMER` and `WOHNUNG`

If clicked the first time they become true and trigger the results to be filtered and if clicked again it has to become false again and restore the old filtering.

Comment: Your website is on your localhost so no one here will be able to access it. To solve this it would help a lot to at least see your HTML, although my first guess is that you've used duplicate `id` attributes on your elements.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I edited it. I am so in rage right now, need to calm down. Will check for id's thanks for the hint

Comment: Post html here.

Comment: I have an idea now why it could be, I have indeed duplicate id`s because yesterday I added a different style for mobile and therefore I duplicated the div with and made one div hidden-xs and the other visible-xs. Will test if that caused the error

Comment: Well the 2nd div style caused the error, thanks @Rory McCrossan wasted so much time but havent looked for the most obvious :(